# Import sql with 2 merged columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Hello I received an large sql to import into my database with 9k lines. The problem is the structure is not really the same.

The header of the table is:

```
Name,Bday,Email,Phone
```

and i received it like this

```
INSERT INTO `Persons` (`Firstname`, `Lastname`, `Bday`, `Email`, `Phone`) VALUES 
('DRAGHICI', 'CLAUDIA', '1963-03-06', '', '0730010099'),
('CIMPEANU', 'ADRIAN GEORGE', '1975-03-06', '', '0747137312'),
('SIRBU', 'CRISTINA', '1985-05-17', '', '0726498751'),
('GHITA', 'DORU AURELIAN', '1962-04-20', '', '0722628325'),
('PALL', 'PETRISOR', '1980-06-24', '', '0745524485'),
('ZMARAND', 'MIHAELA', '1983-10-13', '', '23365646'),
('CHIRIAC', 'PETRE', '1948-04-26', '', '0745789651'),
('ZABAD', 'OMRAN MOHSEN', '1986-06-14', '', '0723368085'),
('TARA', 'SERGIU', '1974-12-01', '', '0722457299'),
('DRACULET', 'CLAUDIA OLIMPIA', '1978-01-22', '', '0745617755'),
('CINDEA', 'PETRISOR', '1970-01-17', '', '0351404534'),
('SAVESCU', 'ADRIANA MADALINA', '1980-09-12', 'madalina_savescu@yahoo.com', '0740699853'),
('POPA', 'SIMINA CLAUDIA', '1980-03-24', '', '0727 346126'),
('GHEORGHE', 'CONSTANTIN', '1986-02-04', '', '0760 244 833'),
('GEORGESCU', 'MARIETA', '1959-08-14', '', '0351422999'),
('SARBU', 'IULIAN', '1947-06-22', '', '0726565154'),
('CALAFETEANU', 'EMIL', '1954-03-20', '', '0745481772'),
('SURPATEANU', 'GEORGETA', '1952-01-26', '', '0743331284'),
('LIMBAN', 'DELIA MIHAELA', '1987-07-15', '', '222356'),
('MARCIU', 'ION', '1944-05-13', '', '0351407891'),
```

I need to merge `firstname lastname` into column `name`

Comment: Please, dont share real names with phone numbers in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Some Other Table

```
create table TempTable(FName varchar(100),
LName varchar(100),Bday datetime,Email varchar(30),Phone int)
```

then insert theses values

```
insert into TempTable(FNamem,LName,Bday,Email,Phone)
-- 9 k rows
```

then do something like this:

```
insert into OriginalTable (Name,Bday,Email,Phone)
select FNamem,LName,Bday,Email,Phone
from TempTable
```

Comment: thnx, i did like you said combined with what noob said i had to concat those 2 colums

Answer (score 1):

Just do what @ganesh_devlekar suggested except make this change in last query:

```
insert into OriginalTable (Name,Bday,Email,Phone)
select CONCAT(FNamem,' ',LName),Bday,Email,Phone
from TempTable
```

Comment: thnx, gna give you an up when i have the raputation for it :)